# write a mysql query in a "before insert into" trigger to disable a foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, triggers, foreign-keys

i have mysql table which have a foreign key that reference across multiple tables.

```
create table phone(
    pid int not null,
    ptid int,
    user_id int,
    constraint onefk foreign key (user_id,ptid) references userone (id,tid),
    constraint twofk foreign key (user_id,ptid) references usertwo (id,tid),
    primary key (pid)
);
```

i want to disable **twofk** foreign key when adding records to **phone** table that reference to **userone** table and disable **onefk** foreign key when adding records to **phone** table that reference to **usertwo** table.how can i do this in a "before insert into" trigger.and i want to enable those constraints in "after insert into" trigger.please help in advance.

Comment: Please don't post long single line code.

Comment: Short answer: It's not possible. Long answer: Well - it depend's on what you really try to do. It seems like you want to define a polymorphic relation. You will either need to remove the FKs or redesign your schema.